# How to print out a string in a pre-given position of a line in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have an assignment to implement a light text editor in C++, one of the functionalities can be simplified to the following requirement.

For instance, I have two strings: "stackoverflow" and "stackexchange". I am asked to print "stack" at the leftest position and overflow" at the rightest position.

I am having two questions:

1. The length of each output line should be fixed, but how to control this length in C++? For instance, I get get input parameter of line length as 200. How to use this 200 to handle my case?
2. How to pinpoint the position of a string in a length? For this example, the length of "stack" is 5, then the starting position for "overflow" should be "200-5-8+1 = 188".

How to do this in C++?

Comment: What should happen with *stackexchange*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can use the `std::setw()` and `std::right` manipulators, which allow to set the field with and the adjustment flags in the stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << "stack" << std::right << std::setw(188) << "overflow" << std::endl;
```

2) You can use the facilities built into `std::string` to find the position of a particular substring:

```
std::string s("stackoverflow");
std::size_t p = s.find("overflow");
if (p != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "Found substring 'overflow' at position: " << int(p) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Append spaces after the first word.